# Prevent automatic hash function for mutable classes

Tags: boost-python

Python allows hash values only for immutable objects. For example,

```
hash((1,2,3))
```

works, but

```
hash([1,2,3])
```

raises a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. See the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-hashable). However, when I wrap a C++ class in Boost.Python via the usual `boost::python::class_<>` function, every generated Python class has a default hash function, where the hash value is related to the object's location in memory. (On my 64-bit OS, the hash value is the location divided by 8.)

When I expose a class to Python whose members can be changed (any mutable data structure, so this is a very common situation!), I do not want a default hash function but want a call to `hash()` raise the same `TypeError` as users receive for Python's own mutable data types. In particular, users shouldn't be able to accidentally use mutable objects as dictionary keys. How can I achieve this in the C++ code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how it goes:

```
boost::python::class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
  .setattr("__hash__", boost::python::object());
```

A `boost::python::object` which is initialized with no arguments corresponds to `None`. The procedure for disabling hash generation in the pure Python C API is a little more complicated, as is described in the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/typeobj.html#PyTypeObject.tp_hash). However, the above code snippet apparently does the job in boost::python.

Answer (score 0):

On a sidenote: The Boost.Python behaviour mirrors the default behaviour of classes in Python, where objects are basically hashable as of object id (derived from id(x)):

```
>>> hash(object())
8795488122377
>>> class MyClass(object): pass
... 
>>> hash(MyClass)
878579
>>> hash(MyClass())
8795488082665
>>>
```