# Boost Python Hash

Tags: python, c++, boost, hash, boost-python

Is there a function in Boost::Python that lets you get the hash of a `boost::python::object`, a.k.a the equivalent of Python's `hash` function? I've been reading the docs, but it doesn't seem to mention anything.

Comment: maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15180520/85371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hash` in python is implemented with `PyObject_Hash` on the C side of things. If you have a random object `obj`, you can simply call:

```
long hash = PyObject_Hash(obj.ptr())
```

The `ptr()` method on a `boost::python::object` returns a `PyObject *` that has a borrowed reference to that object.

In general, there's tons of stuff in the [CPython API](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/) that is not wrapped by boost::python.  It's easy enough to just call it directly.

Comment: I've used the C API, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to go through those waters...oh well.

Comment: It's really not so bad.  There is little downside in cases like this.